# Cloudflare выдаёт ошибку 502 при использовании OpenVPN на веб-сервере

Tags: apache2, openvpn, cloudflare

Здравствуйте! На моем веб-сервере стоит Apache2 и OpenVPN. Когда OpenVPN подключён, на сервер можно зайти через локальную сеть, но через CloudFlare выдаёт ошибку 502 Bad Gateway. Когда VPN отключен ошибки нет.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было убрать/закоментировать в конфиге строку  `redirect-gateway`.